# Associativity of natural join

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra, natural-join

I am wondering whether the natural join operation in relational algebra is associative. I mean, is the following equation true?

```
(S1 NATURAL JOIN S2) NATURAL JOIN S3 = S1 NATURAL JOIN (S2 NATURAL JOIN S3)
```

It looks associative to me intuitively, but i am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `inner join` only returns rows that match the `on` condition.  It does not have special treatment for either the right or the left hand table.  So an `inner join` is associative.

A `natural join` is an `inner join` on all columns with the same name.  Since an `inner join` is associative, so is a `natural join`.

Comment: A natural join is not an inner join (theta-join). An inner/theta join outputs a column for each column in the inputs; it's a restricted cross join. A natural join outputs one column for each column name in the input; so it outputs fewer columns when a column name is shared. Anyway, in algebra natural join inputs any pair of relations, but inner/theta join with only relation values on input is undefined when there are common column names. In SQL there are similar but different differences; SQL joins input relation values and (correlation) names.